# Detect Face and Generate ID for every face & take Screenshot using YoloV5

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition, yolov5

I am doing face recognition Project using YoloV5. The Project have 3 parts.

1. Face Recognition [its already done]
2. Generate unique Face ID on detected face. [Not Done. Need Help/Suggestion]
3. Take Screenshot of every detected face. [Not Done. Need Help/Suggestion]

I have already tried. But I don't understand how to implement this 2 & 3 in YoloV5.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: the keyword you need is "re-id" (re-identification). yolo tells you where faces are, but it won't give you specific features for a face that are suitable for re-identification. you'll need a second network for that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.